# `Ember.Select` for boolean attributes is returning empty object `{}`

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to use a Ember.Select on a boolean attribute on my model. The problem is that it is converting my attribute to an object {} and no binding occurs.

My model has an isActive flag

```
isActive: DS.attr('boolean'),
```

Here is the ember select in my template

```
            {{view Ember.Select
                viewName="isActive"
                content=controller.yesNo
                optionLabelPath="content.key"
                optionValuePath="content.value"
                selection=model.isActive
                class="form-control"
                disabled=true}}
```

In my router I set the yesNo array on the controller (as an aside, I am not sure if this is the correct place to do this, this one is simple but some of my selects require querying the database using `this.store.find('accounts')` so I think these go in the route not the controller).

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);

    controller.set('yesNo', [
        {key : 'Yes', value : true},
        {key : 'No', value : false}
    ]);
}
```

I have also tried passing the boolean values as string but it does not work.

```
    controller.set('yesNo', [
        {key : 'Yes', value : 'true'},
        {key : 'No', value : 'false'}
    ]);
```

### update

From ember inspector, when I select an item it is returning the whole object `{ key: Yes, value: true }` or `{ key: No, value: false }`.  I wan't it to return the value property only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`selection` binds the whole object. `value` will bind just the property specified in `optionValuePath` to the property you specify. Thus, use `value` instead of `selection` if you just want the binded property to be a boolean. Therefore, in your select's handlebars in the template use:

```
{{view Em.Select
  // Properties...
  // More properties...
  value=isActive
}}
```

Sidenote:

You don't need to specify `controller` in `content=controller.yesNo`. You can just say `content=yesNo`.